# Java Custom Exception on Class Level

Tags: java, exception

Can we create an custom exception for a class Level.
For example I have a Class A, now when I create a given object or When I call a given method, I would like yo throw my custom exception.

Comment: I haven't understand the question, do you mean how to create our own exception?

Answer (score 2):

This is the easiest way to create your own `Exception`:

```
public class LevelException extends Exception {
    public LevelException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two kind of exceptions `checked` and `unchecked` exceptions.

1. `Unchecked` exceptions are the sub classes of `RuntimeException`, those exceptions don't need to be added explicitly in your method/constructor description, calling code **doesn't have to manage** it explicitly with a `try/catch` block or by throwing it.
2. `Checked` exceptions are the sub classes of `Exception` but not the sub classes of `RuntimeException`, those exceptions need to be added explicitly in your method/constructor description, calling code **have to manage** it explicitly with a `try/catch` block or by throwing it.

Depending of your need, you will chose one of the two possibilities, if you want to enforce calling code to manage it, use `checked` exceptions otherwise use `unchecked` exceptions.

**`Unchecked` exceptions**

How to create it:

```
public class MyException extends RuntimeException {
...
}
```

How to use it:

```
public void myMethod() {
    ...
    if (some condition) {
        throw new MyException();
    }
    ...
}
```

**`Checked` exceptions**

How to create it:

```
public class MyException extends Exception {
...
}
```

How to use it:

```
public void myMethod() throws MyException {
    ...
    if (some condition) {
        throw new MyException();
    }
    ...
}
```

You can find more details about exceptions [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html)